# I have to double click checkbox to change it's status in Marionette ;/

Tags: checkbox, backbone.js, marionette, ecmascript-5

I have a checkbox with class `js-map-source` in my HBS template. I am listening clicks on this checkbox in Marionette view. This part is working correctly - when I click on checkbox I am able to `console.log` checkbox status.

Code:

```
module.exports = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  # something else....

  ui: {
    mapSource: '.js-map-source'
    # something else...
  },

  events: {
    'click @ui.mapSource': 'mapSourceChanged'
    # something else...
  }

  # something else...

  mapSourceChanged: function (event) {
    var switchStatus = $(this.ui.mapSource).is(":checked");
    console.log(`TypeOf: ${typeof switchStatus}; value: ${switchStatus}`);
  },
}
```

So let's click few times. 
Following logs appers in console:

```
TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false`
```

That was expected behaviour.

The problem occurs when I am trying to save this checkbox value (true/false) in my model. Let's add `this.model.set('source', switchStatus)` to the function `mapSourceChanged`.

Now I have to double click checkbox to mark is as checked (visually). But still, I can uncheck checkbox with one click.

Code:

```
module.exports = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  # something else....

  ui: {
    mapSource: '.js-map-source'
    # something else...
  },

  events: {
    'click @ui.mapSource': 'mapSourceChanged'
    # something else...
  }

  # something else...

  mapSourceChanged: function (event) {
    var switchStatus = $(this.ui.mapSource).is(":checked");
    console.log(`TypeOf: ${typeof switchStatus}; value: ${switchStatus}`);
    this.model.set('source', switchStatus);
  },
}
```

Logs:

```
2TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
2TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
2TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
2TypeOf: boolean; value: true
TypeOf: boolean; value: false
2TypeOf: boolean; value: true
```

This `2` on the beginning of the line means that I get the same log again.

What is the reason for this behaviour? How to fix it?

Comment: bit tricky to say from this code - maybe log out your event also as it's most likely a change on the model triggering an event you have the view listening for - logging our the event will give you something to work from

Comment: Are you using any data binding library/is your input wrapped in a label?

Comment: I figured it out. I had an event listener, set on model change. Thank you, guys.